# iOS login with fabric causes error after updated twitter api was updated to Twitter1.11.3

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

iOS login with fabric causes error after updated twitter api was updated to Twitter1.11.3.

This is the code.

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { (session: TWTRSession!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if session != nil {
            self.showActivityIndicator()

            let parameters = [
                "tw_id":session.userID,
                "tw_name" :session.userName,
                "tw_token":session.authToken,
                "device_token":self.defaults.objectForKey("deviceToken") as! String
            ]
            Alamofire.request(.POST, self.uri.usersApi + "/tw_login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { request, response, result in
                    var jsonObj = JSON(result.value!)
                    self.defaults.setObject(jsonObj["id"].int, forKey: "uid")
                    self.defaults.setObject(jsonObj["name"].string, forKey: "current_user_name")
                    self.defaults.setObject(jsonObj["title"].string, forKey: "job_title")
            }
        } else {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Then, this is the error. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
'(TWTRSession!, NSError!) -> Void' is not convertible to 'TWTRLogInCompletion' (aka '(Optional<TWTRSession>, Optional<NSError>) -> ()')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Thank you for your help.

```
 Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion{session, error in
        if session != nil {
            self.showActivityIndicator()

            let parameters = [
                "tw_id":session!.userID,
                "tw_name" :session!.userName,
                "tw_token":session!.authToken,
                "device_token":self.defaults.objectForKey("deviceToken") as! String
            ]
            Alamofire.request(.POST, self.uri.usersApi + "/tw_login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { request, response, result in
                    var jsonObj = JSON(result.value!)
                    self.defaults.setObject(jsonObj["id"].int, forKey: "uid")
                    self.defaults.setObject(jsonObj["name"].string, forKey: "current_user_name")
                    self.defaults.setObject(jsonObj["title"].string, forKey: "job_title")
            }
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```